# How can I obtain constant time access (like in an array) in a data structure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'll get straight to it - is there a way to have a dynamically sized constant-time access data-structure in Haskell, much like an array in any other imperative language?

I'm sure there is a module somewhere that does this for us magically, but I'm hoping for a general explanation of how one would do this in a functional manner :)

As far as I'm aware, `Map` uses a binary tree representation so it has **`O(log(n))`** access time, and lists of course have **`O(n)`** access time.

Additionally, if we made it so that it was immutable, it would be pure, right?

Any ideas how I could go about this (beyond something like `Array = Array { one :: Int, two :: Int, three :: Int ...}` in template Haskell or the like)?

Comment: There's [Data.Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array.html) in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for more of a helpful explanation for how one would go about implementing such a thing in a functional sense - I'll have a read of the source and see what I can find out...

Comment: Data.Array uses GHC.Arr, which defines an array as data Ix i => Array i e = Array !i  !i  !Int (Array# e), which (perhaps mistakenly) implies to me that there is some wizardry going on under the hood?

Comment: Yes, the implementation is compiler-specific. `Array#` is a special type provided by GHC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your key is isomorphic to `Int` then you can use [IntMap](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-IntMap-Strict.html) as most of its operations are `O(min(n,W))`, where `n` is the number of elements and `W` is the number of bits in `Int` (usually 32 or 64), which means that as the collection gets large the cost of each individual operation converges to a constant.

Comment: Ah that's clever! Apparently it uses something called "big-endian patricia trees", which if I'm correct are something similar to tries except the paths are the bit representation of the Int - this means that the path is of maximum length W where W is the number of bits in the Int. This gives the constant worst case time of W as long as your index fits into an Int! Pretty cool.

Comment: So I suppose as long as your key can be split into N parts, where the N <= M, then you can always make a tree with worst case time M, which is constant if M is constant :)

Comment: Yep!  It is similar in spirit to the trick used in radix sort to sort a list of `n` elements with `d` decimals in just `O(n*d)` time, which is linear if `d` is a constant with respect to `n`.

Answer (score 5):

> a dynamically sized constant-time access data-structure in Haskell,

- Data.Array
- Data.Vector

etc etc.

For associative structures you can choose between:

- Log-N tree and trie structures
- Hash tables
- Mixed hash mapped tries

With various different log-complexities and constant factors.

All of these are on hackage.

Comment: Thanks Don! I asked this question hoping for some high level overviews of how things like hash tables and other similar structures are implemented in Haskell, but these are all good leads for some further reading.

Comment: @Tetigi Generally, you'll find some explanations on their hackage pages + a reference to a paper explaining how these data structures are implemented. Hopefully that will suffice, but feel free to come back asking questions about those, quite a few people are familiar with the implementations. I did study them myself too at some point, was really helpful in getting more familiar with these data structures.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that you can't have constant time access arrays in Haskell without compiler/runtime magic.

However, this isn't (just) because Haskell is functional. Arrays in Java and C# also require runtime magic. In Rust you might be able to implement them in unsafe code, but not in safe Rust.

The truth is any language that doesn't allow you to allocate memory of dynamic size, or that doesn't allow you to use pointers is going to require runtime magic to implement arrays.

That excludes any safe language, whether object oriented, or functional.

The only difference between Haskell and eg. Java with respect to Arrays, is that arrays are far less useful in Haskell than in Java, but in Java arrays are so core to everything we do that we don't even notice that they're magic.

There is one way though that Haskell requires more magic for arrays than eg. Java.

With Java you can initialise an empty array (which requires magic) and then fill it up with values (which doesn't).

With Haskell this would obviously go against immutability. So any array would have to be initialised with its values. Thus the compiler magic doesn't just stretch to giving you an empty chunk of memory to index into. It also requires giving you a way to initialise the array with values. So creation and initialisation of the array has to be a single step, entirely handled by the compiler.

Comment: I don't think that's quite true. Haskell has both immutable arrays and mutable arrays. The mutable ones are restricted to `IO` and `ST`. We can use `freeze` (and the more magical `unsafeFreeze`) to convert mutable arrays into immutable ones, as well as `thaw` and `unsafeThaw` to go the other way. Haskell's *mutable* arrays are the ones most similar to arrays in typical imperative languages, and you can use them in pretty much the same ways.

Comment: That's fair enough. But those arrays aren't very haskelly. I'm considering freezing the array as part of the magic

Comment: As you're telling the compiler make me an array with this set of values.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other good answers, it might be useful to say that:

> When restricted to Algebraic Data Types and purity, all dynamically
>   sized data structure must have at least logarithmic worst-case access
>   time.

Personally, I like to call this *the price of purity*.

Haskell offers you three main ways around this:

- **Change the problem**: Use hashes or prefix trees.
- **For constant-time reads** use pure [Arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array) or the more recent [Vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector); they are not ADTs and need compiler support / hidden IO inside. Constant-time writes are not possible since purity forbids the original data structure to be modified.
- **For constant-time writes** use the `IO` or `ST` monad, preferring `ST` when you can to avoid externally visible side effects. These monads are implemented in the compiler.

Comment: In a sense, the (super-)logarithmic cost goes deeper. Every realistic computer architecture has a finite address space. If you can only address 2^64 words of memory natively, but may need to manage arbitrarily sized (potentially absurdly large) arrays, then you'll be forced into some sort of logarithmic multi-step addressing. More practically, modern architectures all use multiple layers of cache, which give non-constant access times on small scales. NUMA systems also have non-constant memory access.

Comment: On extremely large scales, logarithmic access becomes impossible. In the limit (information density approaching that of a black hole), the best you can hope for is a maximal access time proportional to the square root of the memory size.